# Wort für geräuschvolles Trinken

Tags: single-word-request

Wie nennt man lautes Trinken, bei dem man Luft mit einsaugt und dadurch Geräusche produziert? Gibt es ein Wort dazu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das gibt es:

> [**Schlürfen:**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schluerfen) Flüssigkeit geräuschvoll in den Mund einsaugen/
>   schlürfend zu sich nehmen

Und dazu noch die Synonyme:

> einsaugen, einschlürfen, essen, trinken, zu sich nehmen; (umgangssprachlich) **schlabbern**; (norddeutsch umgangssprachlich) labbern; (landschaftlich) schlurfen

Comment: Vorsicht! "Schlurfen" (u statt ü) kenne ich als geräuschvolles Gehen, bei denen ma die Füße nicht richtig vom Boden hebt.